# Converting MIPs instruction to C and reducing the execution

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Assume c-level integer `j` is held in register `$t1`, `$s2` holds c-level integer called `total`, and `$s0` holds the base address of the integer array `vArray`.

```
    addi $t1, $0, $0
LOOP:
    lw $s1, 0($s0)
    add $s2, $s2, $s1
    addi $s0, $s0, 4 
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    slti $t2, $t1, 100
    bne $t2, $s0, LOOP
```

**My solution:**

I think I have figured out the C code, which should be:

```
for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {

    total = total + vArray[j];

}
```

Then the problem ask: rewrite the loop to reduce the number of MIPS instructions executed.

However, I was not able to reduce the number of MIPs instructions executed. To me, I thought the MIPs instruction was already to its basic, and I couldn't come up with another solution that is less than seven execution steps.

After reading suggestions of decrementing, I came up with this, probably a bit clumsy logic.

```
addi $t1, $zero, 404
LOOP: 
subi $t1, $t1, 4
add $s0, $s0, $t1
lw $t2, 0($s0)
add $s2, $s2, $t2
bne $t1, $zero, LOOP
```

Comment: Your C code is wrong in two places: you use `,` instead of `;` in the `for` loop and use `i` instead of `j` as index. Can you show us a proper C equivalent and the compiler assembly output? It might be a simple problem of optimization level.

Comment: I am sorry for the typos. I fixed it above. I have just started learning MIPs in this class, so I am not sure where to see assembly language code yet.

Comment: Since it's just summing the array, you could count downwards instead of upwards. That way you wouldn't need the `slti` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of minimizing instructions, this is the best I can do:

```
  addi $t1, $s0, 400
LOOP:
  lw $s1, 0($s0)
  add $s2, $s2, $s1
  addi $s0, $s0, 4
  bne $s0, $t1, LOOP
```

Comment: Your logic is much clearer than the solution (see above) I came up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The register $t1 is not actually necessary to increment or check.  It is used to know when you have executed 100 times, but you can also figure this out when $s0 has increased by 400.

Comment: There are also some other optimisations if you're trying to minimise the number of cycles, like branch delay slot, though you have said minimise the number of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Also loop unrolling. I.e. forget the whole loop increment thing, just do 100 adds and 100 memory fetch operations.

Comment: The OP seems to aim for smallest code, not fastest. Beside, the load delay slots would mask the loop execution time, so unrolling would probably make no difference.

Comment: OP clearly stated "number of MIPs instructions executed". This is the minimum.

Comment: well if you count the nops inserted by delay slots it's not any less instruction cycles than a loop that takes advantage of the load and jump delays. You will write less instructions per load-and-accumulate, but the assembler will insert nops behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the smallest possible code, I suppose that might be something like:

```
       add $s2, $0, $0     ; initialize sum to 0
       addi $t1, $s0, $400 ; compute pointer limit
LOOP:  lw $s1, 0($s0)      ; load one element
       addi $s0, $s0, 4    ; point to next element
       add $s2, $s2, $s1   ; cumulate result (away from lw to skip delay slot)
       bne $t2, $t1, LOOP  ; loop until pointer reaches limit
       nop                 ; delay slot of the branch
```

Basically, you use the pointer value as the loop exit condition instead of counting iterations in a separate register.

If you wanted to take advantage of the delay slot:

```
       add $s2, $0, $0     ; initialize sum to 0
       addi $t1, $s0, $400 ; compute pointer limit
LOOP:  lw $s1, 0($s0)      ; load one element
       addi $s0, $s0, 4    ; point to next element
       bne $t2, $t1, LOOP  ; loop until pointer reaches limit
       add $s2, $s2, $s1   ; cumulate result (in delay slot)
```

And with loop unrolling:

```
       add $s2, $0, $0     ; initialize sum to 0
       addi $t1, $s0, $400 ; compute pointer limit
LOOP:  lw $s1, 0($s0)      ; load first element
       addi $s0, $s0, 8    ; compute next block address
       add $s2, $s2, $s1   ; cumulate first element
       lw $s1, -4($s0)     ; load second element
       bne $t2, $t1, LOOP  ; loop until pointer reaches limit
       add $s2, $s2, $s1   ; cumulate second element
```

Each load-and-accumulate now takes 3 cycles compared with 4 in the one-step loop above.

There is no point in unrolling the loop any further, since you can't do a load-and-accumulate step in less than 3 instruction cycles (one memory load, one delay slot, one accumulation).

Comment: Thanks so much! I have not got into delay slot, could you briefly explain delay slot or point to some websites?